# What is "heart" as the emotional organ?

Tags: classical-latin, word-request, word-choice, nuance

In English one uses the word "heart" in a variety of ways to express deep emotion, as in "She will always be in our hearts".
Is there a corresponding "emotional organ" in Latin?
How should I go about translating heart-related phrases into Latin in general?

There is of course *cor*, but I'm not sure if it's really used the way "heart" is.
I am not interested in the actual physical organ that pumps blood but the emotions attached to it in English.
My instinct suggests that *pectus* might be more suitable.
For example, "from the bottom of our hearts" could well be *pectore ab imo*.
But is *pectus* a good general substitute or should I be using *cor* as well?

There are certainly other options too, like *iecur*.
Or perhaps some non-organs should be considered as viable alternatives for the same role, as *animus*.

I prefer classical Latin here, but insight from any era is welcome.

Comment: Definitely in the Vulgate it's **cor**. Can't elaborate now

Comment: Dear Joonas, you quoted this in a previous answer "105: Interea tacitae serpunt in viscera flammae
Meanwhile silent flames creep inside." (Viscera 'guts'.) Respectfully,

Comment: *iecur* should be considered too.

Comment: For some related discussion see https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071231181635AAwGWOR&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAADIWof5m6aUQpq9NHh1h_7dfFTjg-IhlZ2RyO90FUKM6YnxS77k-l7fB18SQf913ZPnYXL-qOjORbtp5ztTCzyBYA5HK--jEoX4IyulavVVtb601ljIstrnRM923FXUTGB7IwuZu3KBW1Fi_Oj4rw88-5Sko_49Bm2s2BBwA3q0T

Comment: From the Carmina Burana, the poem that starts with "Omnia sol temperat":

Ama me fideliter / 
Fidem meam nota / 
de corde totaliter / 
et ex mente tota

Comment: @Hugh If you have some uses of *iecur* in mind, I'd be happy to see them in an answer. You could throw in *viscera* too. It's good to have several answers exploring different avenues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smith & Hall give a fairly clear and thorough explanation in 'A Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary', under the headword 'Heart' (page 307), section III, which begins as follows :

The Heart *as the seat of the emotions:*
1. pectus, -oris, *n*. : *to love one's friend with the whole h.,* amicum toto p. [ut dicitur] amare, Cic. Leg. I, 18, 49 : Virg. : *it is the h. that makes eloquent,* p. est quod disertos facit, Quint. 10, 7, 15 : *a h. to friendship true,*, fidae p. amicitiae, Mart. 9, 14.

*animus* is also put forward as 'the soul, especially as the emotional part'.

Use of the word *cor* is considered infrequent in the sense that you are looking for, although *corda* is used for 'the wits', and the authors also claim that 'cordi esse' denotes simply that a thing *is agreeable to one's wishes*.

On the basis of the whole article, it seems that the usages of both *cor* and *pectus* shade into each other in much the same way as in English idiom , where we can take things to heart, hold emotions in our breasts — or secrets, as the Pope is said to hold the names of chosen cardinals, — have heart-felt conversations and so on; but in cases of doubt, *pectus* looks to be the best bet for what you are wanting.

[I don't use Lewis & Short very often, but I should think, because it was based on Smith, that it is in agreement, with a possibly larger number of examples.]