# Coronat Virtus In Corde Mea / Virtue Reigns In My Heart?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

Could this correctly translate to "Virtue Reigns In My Heart"? I prefer to use "coronat" instead of "regnat" but would it still be correct?

I believe that "coronat virtus cor mea" would be a more direct translation to "virtue crowns my heart" which I also like, but I am really hoping to use "Coronat Virtus In Corde Mea" instead.

Comment: *Coronat Virtus In Corde Mea* means my strength is wreathing in the heart, which is probably not what you're trying to say.

Comment: Glancing at the title I read "Corona Virus...".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, *cor* is neutral, so it would have in any event to be *Coronat virtus in corde **meo*** and *Coronat virtus cor **meum***.

As for the verb *coronare*, it means “to furnish with a crown” (often with the crowning material in the ablative, e.g. Jesus is sometimes called *spinis coronatus*, crowned with thorns), or “to surround like a crown” (here the crowning material is sometimes, but not always, the subject). It does not mean “reign” and has no particular association with it either, because in Roman thinking, a *corona* had little to do with royalty or power, and was more (a) a general adornment for festive occasions, and (b) a prize given for achievements in various areas (especially as a military award). One might add that these *coronae* were often garlands of flowers.

So no, you cannot replace *regnat* with *coronat* and hope it more or less means the same.

Comment: So a good translation not too far apart from the OP's would be **Regnat virtus in cor meum**? Trying to remember examples, _super_ cor meum sounds good enough.

Comment: @Rafael *in corde meo*, I'd say.

Comment: This is great, thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Corono is a transitive verb, so the reader will expect it to have an object.

The well known Latin mottoes involving corono, are *Finis coronat opus* (The end crowns the work), and *Coronat virtus cultores suos* (Virtue crowns her followers).

You could write,

***Coronat virtus fanum animi mei.***

Virtue crowns the temple of my heart. (If you change *animi* to *pectoris* and change some words around, you might even get it to scan.)

Concerning the use of the word *cor* as the seat of emotion, [see a previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11421/what-is-heart-as-the-emotional-organ).

Comment: This is great, I love it! So animi is like the emotional soul / heart? This is the concept I was going for. Do I need to change the form of animi mei to reflect that I am female?

Comment: Mei is both masculine and female. The animus is the seat of the intellect in Roman thought, and in situations like this it is the most common word. Pectoris is sometimes found and cor is found less often. Cor has a more of an anatomical sense in Latin. Animus can either be the source of rational thought, but it can also be the source of antipathy, courage, love and other emotions. It has sort of the meaning of the mind. By contrast, the anima (feminine) is the soul, the life force.

Comment: So why animi? Out of curiosity, can you also say Coronot virtus animi pura or virtus coronot animi pura? Thank you for sharing your time and knowledge.

Comment: @user11556 animi is the genitive form ("of the heart/mind") . Corono is transitive, so you need to have an object that is being wreathed.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you!! This is perfect.

Comment: @user11556 If you like the answer, then it is normal to accept it. You can always unaccept it later if you want to.